# I have a issue at Backtrader Lib

Tags: python, back-testing, backtrader

I am interested in backtesting for my strategy  by backtrader but I have a problem in the beginning.

Here is my code:

```
import backtrader as bt

cerebro = bt.Cerebro()

data = bt.feeds.GenericCSVData(dataname='BTCUSDT_15min.csv', dtformat = 2)
cerebro.adddata(data)


cerebro.run()
cerebro.plot()
```

When I run it, the output is:

```
    py", line 98, in <lambda>
    self._dtconvert = lambda x: datetime.utcfromtimestamp(float(x))
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument
```

and it shows `cerebro.run()`